# How to simplify an index number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've just come across a grade A question involving indices:
$$\frac{2^{30}}{8^9} = 2^x$$ Work out the value of $x$. As a tip, the revision guide says to convert $8^9$ to $2^{something}$ so the question can be simplified by subtracting the indices. But I have no idea how to do this and I can't find anything on it.

Answer (score 3):

$$8 = 2^3$$
$$8^9 = (2^3)^9$$

When we raise an exponent to another exponent, we multiply them together:

$$8^9 = (2^3)^9 = 2^{(3*9)} = 2^{27}$$

So now your problem becomes:

$$\frac{2^{30}}{2^{27}} = 2^{(30-27)} = 2^3 = 8$$

Comment: I'd just like to thank you for taking the time to answer this. I know it might've been simple but with a math teacher that never has the time to answer my questions and all my revision books not having anything on this it really means a lot to finally find out how to do this. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Mhm, not a problem! That's what these websites are for, right? If you need any other help don't feel hesitant to post - the community is extremely helpful and has given me a lot of intuition on questions I had previously, even if I thought they might have been simple or trivial. (:

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $8$ can be written as $2^3$. See if this helps you continue with the equation.